# Elasticsearch query - no results matches

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to do something very simple I believe, but don't understand why am I not getting the correct results.

In our Kibana, when in `Discover` tab, if I want to see the history of all data (selecting last 5 years), I get ~500M hits. If I then add a simple filter - `database is postgres-prod`, I get around 137M hits, so the filter in the `Discover` tab works. I can even see the filter DSL (If I go to edit the filter) and it looks like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "database": {
        "query": "postgres-prod",
        "type": "phrase"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Now the problem is when I'm in Kibana Dev Tools and trying to do the same thing. If I do just a `match_all` query, I got the same, ~500M hits as expected:

```
GET /logstash-*/_search

{
    "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    }
}

response:
{
  "took": 2347,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 155,
    "successful": 155,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 500708223,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
```

The problem is that whatever query I'm trying to do, I always get the results of 500M hits, rather than the expected 137M like I see in the discover tab. Even if I'm applying the exact same query I see in the Discover filter, like this:

```
GET /logstash*/_search

{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "database": {
        "query": "postgres-prod",
        "type": "phrase"
      }
    }
  }
}

response:
{
  "took": 2313,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 155,
    "successful": 155,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 500709434,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
```

I also tried many other queries, for example this bool query, but always just got the result of 500M hits. It's like all the queries I'm trying are ignored

```
GET /logstash-*/_search

{
  "query": { 
    "bool": { 
      "must": [
        { "match": {
            "database": {
              "query": "postgres-prod",
              "type": "phrase"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
response:
{
  "took": 2338,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 155,
    "successful": 155,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 500714297,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
```

Anyone knows what could I be doing wrong, why the query is not narrowing down my search?

Comment: I think you are doing a GET call, which doesn't take a Json payload, You might want to try POST

Comment: The problem is that you have an empty line between `GET` and your DSL, you need to remove it and it will work.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Val - removing the empty line did fix the issue I was seeing! Didn't know it's so sensitive.